# AVD errors with HAX on Android Studio 2.1

Tags: android, android-testing

I have a Lenovo W540 Thinkpad with Windows 7 and 8 Gb ram.

I had an old version of Android Studio installed on C:

Since C: was small and have little space left, I uninstalled it, downloaded and installed Android Studio 2.1 on D:

Wanted to run Instrumentation test sample in the emulator. 
(https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing/tree/master/unit/BasicUnitAndroidTest)

Created a default Nexus 5X AVD. Tried to run. 
Constantly get AVD errors. Tried setting the memory sizes manually but to no avail.

Do I need to uninstall HAX and reinstall on D:? (is it even possible)

> Cannot launch AVD in emulator. Output: Hax is enabled Warning:
>   requested ram_size 1024M too big, reduced to 512M
>   qemu-system-x86_64.exe: -drive
>   if=none,index=1,id=cache,file=C:\Users\aphilip.android\avd\Nexus_5X_API_22_1.avd/cache.img:
>   could not open disk image
>   C:\Users\my.android\avd\Nexus_5X_API_22_1.avd/cache.img: Could
>   not open
>   'C:\Users\my.android\avd\Nexus_5X_API_22_1.avd/cache.img':
>   Invalid argument

[image]

**Update:** 
It works now after

- I created environment variable in Computer|Properties ANDROID_SDK_HOME=D:\
- Deleted HAXM and reinstalled
- moved .android to D:

Comment: Please answer your questions below instead of updating the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It works now after

- I created environment variable in Computer|Properties ANDROID_SDK_HOME=D:\
- Deleted HAXM and reinstalled
- moved .android to D: